# Which library is better to go with for text recognition(CNN+RNN+CTC), OpenCV vs Keras vs Tensorflow?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, opencv

I want to build a model to recognize text form images, for this purpose I need CNN stacked with Bidirectional LSTM and CTC. I would like to know which library would be better and how?